# How to and Where to use "?" and "!" in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I didn't find any much difference while using `?` and `!` in Swift. Here is the some example code of when I use `?`

```
var myString:String? = "Ganesh";
    if myString{
        println(myString)
    }else{
        println(myString)
    }
OutPut was: Optional Ganesh

var myString:String? = "Ganesh";
    myString = nil
    if myString{
        println(myString)
    }else{
        println(myString)
    }
 OutPut was: nil
```

and when I use `!`

```
var myString:String! = "Ganesh";
    if myString{
        println(myString)
    }else{
        println(myString)
    }
OutPut was: Ganesh

var myString:String! = "Ganesh";
    myString = nil
    if myString{
        println(myString)
    }else{
        println(myString)
    }
OutPut was: nil
```

Can someone please help me to get brief on it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the technical difference:

When you use `var y : String?`, you have to use `if let x = y { /* do something with x */ }` or `y!` to be able to use the value inside `y`. `y.toInt()` will not work, because `toInt()` does not exist on `Optional<String>`.

When you use `var y : String!`, you are using an implicitly unwrapped optional. When you do `y.toInt()`, it will behave as if you had said `y!.toInt()`. This is the entire difference.

Now, usage:

If at all possible, use variables, return values or properties that aren't optionals at all.

If you must have optionals, if possible, use `?` (ordinary optionals). This clearly signals that the optional may not have a value and that it is as a consequence of the design.

When the implicitly unwrapped optional - `!` - is used, it shows that it is "probably" supposed to have a value, and it is usually used when the information about whether it should be optional or not simply is not available, like Objective-C frameworks. This makes working with values that nearly always have a value easier (because you don't have to type `!` all the time), but it also means that they encourage code that don't check for `nil` and that may therefore crash and burn.

Apple uses the implicitly unwrapped optional when importing Cocoa frameworks, but they are also cleaning up a lot of their own frameworks to use ordinary `?` optionals or non-optionals instead of implicitly unwrapped optionals, since that provides a lot more information about what to expect.

(Update 2014-09-30: I had completely mixed up the advice for "!" and "?" - "?" is meant to be preferred over "!". I have edited the answer.)

Comment: I don't see why you should avoid optionals. Apple makes heavy use of them.

Comment: Obviously, you shouldn't avoid optionals if you have to sometimes signal that a value is missing. That's what they're for. But by not using optionals, the rest of your code can make safe assumptions that a value will always be provided.

Comment: Apple is also combing their frameworks to expose implicitly unwrapped optionals where possible and even non-optionals in some places. They wouldn't do that if that didn't make their frameworks easier, clearer and safer to use.

Comment: @Jesper, Thank you for responding. Finally what I understood is always better to use "!" (implicitly unwrapped optionals) to make code safe. right?

Comment: I just realized I had completely swapped the advice for "!" and "?". I will set the answer right - "?" is preferable to "!" and not the other way around. Sorry for the confusion.